# Missing movie thumbnail in Dolphin Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, thumbnails, dolphin

Since the new 15.10 release, the movie thumbnail is gone from dolphin. It was working before, I did an upgrade from 15.04 and suddely this option disappeard. Any idea how can I get it back ? Thank you!

[image: Dolphin previews window]

Comment: Additional info : The kffmpegthumbnailer (video thumbnailer for KDE) is already installed :

Answer (score 8):

Thank you Palantir! There was indeed a workaround. This is what I did :

```
 sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake extra-cmake-modules kio-dev pkg-config libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev
```

Downloading/compiling/installing:

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/ffmpegthumbs
cd ffmpegthumbs
git checkout origin/frameworks
mkdir -p builddir
cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(kf5-config --prefix) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON
sudo make install
```

And when I restarted Dolphin I found this :

[image]

So it works :)

Comment: Good to know. Will do that myself :D

Comment: Fantastic! Actually you send me the link :)

Comment: Didn't work for me, it said it had unmet dependencies :(

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is a bug. You can find the bug report here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/1505014

There is no simple fix. Try reading the bug report if there are workarounds suggested.